# perl imap move message to trash (Mail::IMAPClient)

Tags: perl, email, imap

I need to move all messages from unseen to the trash(and delete then from inbox).

```
my $inbox = $imap->select("Inbox");
my @mails = ( $imap->unseen );

foreach my $msgid (@mails) {
    $imap->set_flag( "Deleted", @mails )
        or die "Could not set flag: $@\n";
}
```

This code delete messages completely. (without expunge too)

I tried to use "move" and "copy":

```
my $Trash = "Trash";
my $newUid = $imap->move( $Trash, $msgid )
    or die "Could not move: $@\n";
my $uidList = $imap->copy( $Trash, @mails )
    or die "Could not copy: $@\n";
```

But "move" create new mark(folder) and "copy" dont work "Could not copy: 6 NO [TRYCREATE] No folder Trash (Failure)"
I tried to use name: /Trash, [imap]Trash etc., similar results. 
This must work for different mail services!

i use [`Mail::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient)

Comment: Which imap package do you use? [Do not insist on unnecessary guesswork]

Comment: oh, i forgot to write 
Mail::IMAPClient

Comment: Which folders you can see? `my $folders = $imap->folders or die "List folders error: ", $imap->LastError, "\n"; print "Folders: @$folders\n";`

Comment: yes, i have [Gmail]/Trash but if i change mail service?

Comment: and it does not work on the Cyrillic alphabet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code below for imap servers supporting [RFC6154](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154) [like Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions). It should detect Trash folder name.

```
use  Mail::IMAPClient; 
 ......
my $Trash;
{
  my @Trash;
  my @fhashes = $imap->folders_hash or die "Could not get list of folder hashes.\n";
  foreach my $fhash (@fhashes) {
    next unless map { /^\\Trash$/ ? ($_) : () } @{$fhash->{attrs}};
    push (@Trash, $fhash->{name});
  }
  $Trash = pop( @Trash) if @Trash == 1;
}
if( defined( $Trash)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes! It's work for me with english, ukrainian and russian language.
(i change this push(@Trash, $fhash->{name});)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Bugfix done.  I have been brave/stupid to modify code after tests.  Anyway you should treat it as a working prototype.

Comment: i find mail service who have trash folder as TRASH. I'm sorry, but how to add the "TRASH" in the regular expression?

Comment: To check folder attribute in case insensitive manner use `/^\\Trash$/i`. **IF** `@Trash==0` **THEN** as fall-back you may check existence of any folder on predefined lists of likely names of Trash folder.