# /Deleted flag imap collector

Tags: perl, imap

[my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138604/perl-imap-move-message-to-trash-mailimapclient/)

I write collector for imap (perl). There was a question, if the user marks a message as deleted, what should happen with the message from which I gathered all? Remove it completely, or move in a trash, or create a new archive folder for these messages? If I flagged /Deleted gmail and yandex, for example, removes it completely, my work mail service move letter to trash folder. What is the correct implementation?

Comment: That's usually configurable or a policy decision.  Many clients will move to some Trash folder by default.  Some clients support a Shift-Delete (or similar combination) to mean Delete Bypassing Trash.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are doing. Presumably, you're working on a program which serves some purpose. What is that purpose?

If you are writing some tool which accesses an IMAP account as a client, then you should not handle any sorts of policies such as "what to do with deleted messages". Some other IMAP client marked that message as `\Deleted`, and the server decided that it's good to implement IMAP's usual two-phase deleted with `\Deleted` and `EXPUNGE`. There are, as you already mentioned, other possible policies where the server might auto-expunge upon seeing the `\\Deleted` flag getting set, perhaps by moving the e-mail to a virtual Trash folder, etc. As an observer of an IMAP account, though, you are most likely not suppossed to care.